# How do you get this div element to appear after button.addEventListener is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, fetch

Basically I am trying to use Bootstrap's accordion drop-down menus to appear when a player is searched up after the button is pressed. Here is my code:

```
    <form>
        <div class="userContainer">
            <button id="submitButton"><i class="fi-xnsuxl-search"></i></button>
            <input class = "form-control" id = "displayUsers" type = "text" placeholder="Username/UUID" aria-label = "Search">
        </div>
    </form>

    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div id="skin_container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /> <br />
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="panel-group" id="faqAccordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default ">
                <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question0">
                     <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#" class="ing">BuildUHC</a>
                  </h4>
    
                </div>
                <div id="question0" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                         <h5><span class="label label-primary"><div class = "container-stats-1"></div></span></h5>
    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default ">
                <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed question-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question1">
                     <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#" class="ing">Combo</a>
                  </h4>
    
                </div>
                <div id="question1" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                         <h5><span class="label label-primary"><div class = "container-stats-2"></div></span></h5>
    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default ">
                <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed question-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question2">
                     <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#" class="ing">Potion</a>
                  </h4>
    
                </div>
                <div id="question2" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                         <h5><span class="label label-primary"><div class = "container-stats-3"></span></h5>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default ">
                <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed question-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question3">
                     <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#" class="ing">Parkour</a>
                  </h4>
    
                </div>
                <div id="question3" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                         <h5><span class="label label-primary"><div class = "container-stats-4"></span></h5>
                             
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/panel-group-->
    </div>
```

I have it setup in JavaScript as:

```
const button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
button.addEventListener("click", fetchUser);
```

fetchUser is the function I created to display data when it fetches from the API it's using. I want it to basically show the container-fluid div when it is pressed and fetches data, not at the start of the page. It would also be nice to have an "Error: Not a valid player" message show up if the API doesn't find anybody, but that's another issue for another time I suppose.

Hopefully you can help me out,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the code, where you try to make the accordeon appear( fetchUser-function)?

Comment: I don't use fetchUser() to make it appear. I have nothing setting it to appear at the moment, I'm just genuinely confused on where to start lol.

Comment: I think, how to show a html-element is described on many other places. Do you want to use only plain javascript or do you use any Framework like react.js, vue.js,...?

Comment: What is your exact requirement?